# Mapping of a finite set onto itself

Tags: monomorphisms

I'm studying Herstein's Topics in Algebra and stumbled upon the following problem (Chapter 0, section 2, problem 8):

If the set S has a finite number of elements, prove the following:

(a) If $\sigma$ maps S onto S, then $\sigma$ is one-to-one.

(b) If $\sigma$ is a one-to-one mapping of S onto itself, then $\sigma$ is onto.

(c) Prove, by example, that both part (a) and part (b) are false if S does not have a finite number of elements.

Where i can solve (b) and (c) with no difficulty but I can't quite wrap my head around (a) because i seem to have been able to come up with a counterexample, a very simple one at that. My reasoning is the following:

Let $S$ be the set containing elements $x_1$ and $x_2$. Let $\sigma :S\rightarrow S$ be such that $\sigma(x_1)=x_1$ and $\sigma(x_2)=x_1$. I've therefore constructed a mapping $\sigma$ which maps $S$ onto $S$ where $S$ is finite but $\sigma$ is not injective (one-to-one or a monomorphism).

Where's the flaw in my reasoning?

Comment: $\sigma$ is not onto, since nothing gets mapped to $x_2$

Comment: So then that means the phrase "If  $\sigma$ maps $S$ onto $S$" is the same as "If  $\sigma$ is an onto mapping from $S$ to $S$"? If so, would that mean (a) and (b)  are like "inverse" problems?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @AlejandroAguilar yes and yes (though the proper term is "converse", not "inverse")

Comment: (b) is a little peculiar, as it appears to assume its conclusion. It's better phrased as, if $S$ is finite, and $\sigma$ is a one-one map of $S$ to itself, then $\sigma $ is onto.